# AJAX request.term returning null; jQuery Autocomplete Textbox, .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**View:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#OriginInput").autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("AjaxMethod","MyUrl")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                 data: { id: request.term },
                 success: function (data) {
                     response($.map(data, function (item) {
                         return { label: item.label, value: item.id };
                     }));
                 }
             });
         },
        minLength: 2
    });
```

**Controller**

```
    public static List<PostalCodeModel> ListOfPostalCode;
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string x)
    {
        x = Request.QueryString["term"];

        var locations = ListOfPostalCode.Where(r => x != null && (r.City.StartsWith(x) || r.State.StartsWith(x) || r.Zip.StartsWith(x) || r.Country.StartsWith(x))).Take(25).Select(r => new { id = r.ToString(), label = r.ToString(), name = r.ToString() });
        return Json(locations, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

**Model**

```
        public class PostalCodeModel
{
    public PostalCodeModel(string c, string s, string z, string o)
    {
        City = c;
        State = s;
        Zip = z;
        Country = o;
    }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // trim to remove unnecessary spaces
        return City.Trim() + ", " + State.Trim() + ", " + Zip.Trim() + ", " + Country.Trim();
    }
```

Every time I make this call in my autocomplete box, x returns null in my Controller and thus does not parse any info from the list of postal codes. Not included is the query that initializes my complete list of postal codes in Controller (which is 190000 or so items large), but it seems to work fine.

I assume the main issue is with my ajax in the view not passing the "OutputText" box to the request/response, but I can't seem to find the problem when searching elsewhere. Thanks for any and all help; just started using JavaScript a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax method you are sending the wrong data. It should be like this.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AjaxMethod", "MyUrl")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { term: request.term },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
            return { label: item.label, value: item.id };
        }));
    }
});
```

Also you don't need to get parameter with `Request.QueryString["term"];`

Change

```
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string x)
```

to

```
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string term)
```

Also don't forget to null check term.

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: yep. Sorry, new to asking Q's on this site